# design decision tree survey using django dynamic forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I need to build a survey tool which provides an interface to the survey administrator to add/edit/delete questions. I understand we can do it through the django dynamic forms in admin interface. But can we provide branched/skip logic feature so that the administrator can design a survey where the next question to be displayed will depend on the response of the previous question? I mean this branch logic feature will allow the survey administrator to create a decision tree survey.

Comment: The logic and functionality will be in your `views.py` and your `models`. The `forms` are there to only provide interface and validation. If you ask question `A` and need to load question `B` based on the answer, you have to link those in your models/views. JMHO.

Comment: yes, I am implementing this now. As of now, I have most of my logic in views.py.